# does firebase ios app automatically watch for new build/release if available?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-fabric, firebase-app-distribution

I am migrating app from fabric to Firebase crashlytics. when I release new version or new build from Firebase, I  am  seeing notification in email but I am not seeing notification inside the app or launch the app. is this feature missing in Firebase?